# How can I parse json array from json object?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, iterated-function

I have a json object being returned from a get request in reactjs. I am wanting to get key and value items from this.

```
{"return":"Success",

"Items": [

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"rollover" ,  "Os":"Windows",  "Level":"1", "Language_Used":"Assembly", "Size":"4mb"},

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"Atype" ,   "Os":"Linux"  ,  "Level":"3", "Language_Used":"C++"     , "Size":"4mb"},

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"random" ,  "Os":"OSX"    ,  "Level":"2", "Language_Used":"C"       , "Size":"4mb"}

]}
```

I noticed I can access the values manually using the code below.

Keep in mind, that this.state.stuff is holding my json object. Is my format json format bad for what I am trying to do?

```
if(this.state.authenticated ){
            {this.GetPage.bind(this)}
            let x = this.state.stuff; Object.entries(this.state.stuff).map((type,item) => {

            console.log(type[1][0])
            console.log(type[1][1])
            console.log(type[1][2])
          })
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, and you haven't explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited this. Sorry, I didn't think it was too terrible of a question.

Comment: I didn't expect to be so punished for it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to be able to get the key and values within the Object Items arrays, so you need to map over items array and then the `key, values` from the obtained item with `Object.entries()`

You can do it like

```
 if(this.state.authenticated ){
        {this.GetPage.bind(this)}
        this.state.stuff.Items.map((item, index) => {
             Object.entries(item).forEach([key, value], () => {
                    console.log(key, value)
             })

      })
```

Working example

```
var obj = {"return":"Success",

"Items": [

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"rollover" ,  "Os":"Windows",  "Level":"1", "Language_Used":"Assembly", "Size":"4mb"},

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"Atype" ,   "Os":"Linux"  ,  "Level":"3", "Language_Used":"C++"     , "Size":"4mb"},

{"Name":"centracore", "Type":"random" ,  "Os":"OSX"    ,  "Level":"2", "Language_Used":"C"       , "Size":"4mb"}

]}
obj.Items.map((item, index) => {
       console.log( item);
       Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
              console.log(key, value)
       })

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/xc8yh1dh/1/)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks didn't see  it earlier :)